# How to edit the name of a plugin on wordpress.org/plugins

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org

Is there a way to edit the plugin name published on the WordPress plugin repository?

I tried editing the source code, but it still shows the old name.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Edit it where? In the plugin repository? Or just in your WordPress install? If only for your install, do you need to change it in Plugins > Installed Plugins, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  [Official Answer](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-developer-faq/#can-i-change-my-plugins-name-after-its-approved)! is

> Yes and no. You can change the display name, but the slug — that part of the >plugin URL that is yours — cannot be changed once a plugin is approved. That’s why we warn you, multiple times, upon submission.

> To change the display name, edit your main plugin file and change the value of “Plugin Name:” to the new name. You also will want to edit your header in your readme.txt to match.